# Adding another property to my result

Tags: active-directory, powershell-4.0

How can I change:

```bsh
Search-ADAccount -AccountExpiring -UsersOnly -TimeSpan 14.00:00:00 |
  Get-ADUser -Properties Manager,AccountExpirationDate,LastLogonDate,Givenname |
  Select-Object Name, Givenname, AccountExpirationDate, LastLogonDate,
                SamAccountName, @{Name="Manager";Expression={
                  $_.Manager | Get-ADUser -Properties emailaddress |
                    Select-Object -ExpandProperty emailaddress
                }}
```

So that I get the "manager's" first name too?  I tried just adding:

```bsh
@{Name="Manager";Expression={
  $_.Manager | Get-Aduser -properties GivenName |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty GivenName
}
```

But the script prompts me for input.  I can't figure out why so it would look like this:

```bsh
Search-ADAccount -AccountExpiring -UsersOnly -TimeSpan 14.00:00:00 |
  Get-ADUser -Properties Manager, AccountExpirationDate, LastLogonDate, Givenname |
  Select-Object Name, Givenname, AccountExpirationDate, LastLogonDate,
                SamAccountName, @{Name="Manager";Expression={
                  $_.Manager | Get-Aduser -Properties emailaddress |
                    Select-Object -ExpandProperty emailaddress
                }, @{Name="GivenName";Expression={
                  $_.Manager | Get-Aduser -Properties GivenName |
                    Select-Object -ExpandProperty GivenName
                }}
```

Comment: That should be Name="GivenName" in the last expression, I did that right when I tried it...

Comment: a) Calculated properties have 2 opening curly brackets, so they also require 2 closing ones (one for the `expression` scriptblock, the other for the property hashtable). b) You can't select 2 properties with the same name (`GivenName`).